# Match duplicated column names to data table

Tags: r, data.table

```
letters <- data.frame(name=c("a","b","b","b","c","d","d","e"), 
                      row.names=c("a","b","b.1", "b.2", "c","d", "d.1", "e"))
table <- data.table(label=c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"),
                    a=c(0,0,0,1,1), b=c(1,1,3,4,0), c=c(1,2,3,4,5), d=c(1,0,0,0,0), e=c(1,1,1,1,1))
```

I have a data frame, letters, of alphanumeric characters corresponding to their original alphabetical letter.
I also have a data table, table, that keeps track of the count of each color for each alphabetical letter, but I'd like this data table to include the alphanumeric characters as columns with the same values as their original alphabetical character. So, in table, I want to add the columns b.1=c(1,1,3,4,0), b.2=c(1,1,3,4,0), and d.1=c(1,0,0,0,0). How would I go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- find row names in `letters` that have alphanumeric values in them.
- remove numbers from it to subset columns from `table`.
- `cbind` the new columns to original `table`.

```
new_col <- grep('[a-z]\\.[0-9]', rownames(letters), value = TRUE)
sub_col <- sub('\\.\\d+', '', new_col)
cbind(table, setNames(table[, ..sub_col], new_col))

#    label a b c d e b.1 b.2 d.1
#1:    red 0 1 1 1 1   1   1   1
#2: orange 0 1 2 0 1   1   1   0
#3: yellow 0 3 3 0 1   3   3   0
#4:  green 1 4 4 0 1   4   4   0
#5:   blue 1 0 5 0 1   0   0   0
```

where

```
new_col
#[1] "b.1" "b.2" "d.1"
sub_col
#[1] "b" "b" "d"
```